# why doesn't my custom spring login form work

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am really struggling with Spring Security. I have been trying all day (like 10 hours now), to get a simple example working.

The problem I have is that the login form just doesn't do anything. I post it to various URL's to try to trigger even an error, but it just gets a 404 at the Url.

Can anyone tell me what the form supposed to post to, in order for spring security to work?

The login form is:

```
<%@ include file="../../../../common/partials/commonIncludes.jsp" %>
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="url"/>
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN FORM -->
<form:form commandName="systemUser" class="login-form" action="${url}" method="post">
    <tags:csrf />
    <h3 class="form-title">Login to your account</h3>
    <div class="alert alert-error display-hide">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            <span>
                 Enter any username and password.
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"/> Remember me </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
            Login </button>
    </div>
    <div class="forget-password">
        <h4>Forgot your password ?</h4>
        <p>
            no worries, click <a href="javascript:;" id="forget-password">here</a>
            to reset your password.
        </p>
    </div>
</form:form>
<!-- END LOGIN FORM -->
```

My SecurityConfig class looks like this:

```
package com.ideafactory.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Creates the security configuration.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")  // #1
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin") // #2
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN","USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/login", "/admin/login/new**", "/admin/register", "/admin/logout", "/assets/**", "/admin/session/timeout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/customers")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/admin/login?error")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
                //.requiresChannel()
                //.antMatchers("/admin/login/new", "/admin/login").requiresSecure()
                //.antMatchers("/admin/logout").requiresInsecure()
                //.and()
    }

}
```

Comment: mail me your complete project or give me your email to send you a working example

Comment: It's okay I got it working, it could have been a few things, but I had the wrong servlet version in web.xml (needed 3.0), and also explicitly added j_spring_security_check as the login processing url. It was probably one of those that fixed it.